# Get user_ID from Modal via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pass the ID's for each modal for fetched rows. If I try to get the edit_id value, it returns always the first fetched value. What am I missing? Can somebody please help me?

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_set)){?>

            <li class="gen-row">
                <div class="gen">

                    <div class="gen-controls">
                        <div class="gen-control"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></div>

                        <!-- Edit Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Erstellen Sie ein neues Genogramm </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">

                                        <form action="edit_data.php" method="post" id="genogramm-anlegen">
                                            <input type="text" id="edit_id" name='edit_id' value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'>
                                        </form>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" form="genogramm-anlegen" name="btn_edit">Speichern</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>


            <?php
        }
```

The edit_data.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_edit'])) {

$user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['edit_id']);

echo $user_id;
```

Comment: you change modal ID, but edit_id and btn_edit are always the same, edit_data.php can be also used with a GET a parameter, such as edit_data.php?id=my_row_id, even jquery, you have many solution

Comment: thx! That's the problem... I changed it to: `<input type="text" id="edit_id" name='edit_id<?php echo $row[0]; ?>' value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'>` but how can I get it afterwords?

Comment: is that your full code inside your while loop, please post all code inside your while loop. And also inspect element on your browser first and see each modal is getting unique ID or not.

Comment: @webdev yes, its almost the whole while loop. Just closing brackets. The modals get their unique ID, but I think the problem is as OldPadawan said, that the edit_id and the ban_edit aren't. I just don't know now, how I can get them in my edit_data.php since they are changing. But there should be a solution... I'm trying

Comment: Yeah you are right , but it can be a quick fix i think if you can put your submit button inside your form. Just a thought

Comment: WHY? :D thx man... it worked...